# React Native - Image Component does not accept variable for Source URI attribute

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

A parent component passes down data received through a database call to the child component.

My code for the child component being rendered is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Image, View, Text } from 'react-native'

class ListItem extends Component {
  render () {
    const { name, image } = this.props.item

    return <View>
      <Image
        style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
        source={{ uri: image }} />
      <Text>
        {name}
      </Text>
    </View>
  }
}

export default ListItem
```

With the code above, no image shows up, although a 50 x 50 element does take up space (seen using inspector).

The URL being tested works fine and the image shows up in the app when hard-coded as such:

`source={{ uri: 'test URL here' }}`

I've also used `console.log` to check that the `image` prop exists before the `return` call. Everything indicates that the URL (ie the `image` prop) already exists from the database call.

On a side-note, I was originally using react-native's `ListItem` component and passing it the `image` prop as its `avatar` attribute; the same issue occurs where the image doesn't show up, just a grey box. This is also fixed by setting the following:

`avatar={'test URL here'}`

Answer (score 0):

Are we 100% sure `image` is a string? Since it works when hardcoding the url, perhaps the `image` prop isn't strictly a string

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  render () {
    const { name, image } = this.props.item;
    const sourceUri = { uri: image };

    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
          source={sourceUri} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ListItem;
```